# Hibernate weird behaviour with Set<Enum[]>

Tags: java, hibernate

So I'm trying to save a field which is Set of Arrays of Enum type.

basically:
`Set<Color[]>`

Now, for single enums I've used annotation

`@ElementCollection(targetClass = Color.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

That worked alright so I've tried to use

`@ElementCollection(targetClass = Color[].class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<Color[]> availableColorCombinations;`

on my field but I've some weird behaviour. I'm writing only 6 values here:

```
        colors.add(new Color[] {Color.CHROM, Color.CHROM});
        colors.add(new Color[] {Color.BIANCO, Color.WHITE});
        colors.add(new Color[] {Color.GOLD, Color.GOLD});
        colors.add(new Color[] {Color.NERO, Color.BLACK});
        colors.add(new Color[] {Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK});
        colors.add(new Color[] {Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE});
```

But my object (when I'm taking it from database) says, that I have over 200 arrays in this Set, which are this 6 values but added many, many times.

What is this about, why does that happen? And most importantly - what is the best way to store `Set<Enum[]>` in database?

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that arrays do not implement "deep" equality, i.e., even if two arrays `a` and `b` have the exact same size and elements, they are reported as being different by their `equals` implementation, and will very likely have different hash codes:

```
a.equals(b) => false
```

Since many `Set` implementations will rely on a suitable definition of object equality for their elements, they will consider these arrays to be different.

Observe, how

```
public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object[] a1 = new Object[] { "foo" };
        final Object[] a2 = new Object[] { "foo" };
        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));
        System.out.println(a1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(a2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

produces

```
false
1342443276
769287236
```

One potential solution would be to use proper collections instead of arrays to hold the colour values. Since `Collection`s are supposed to provide proper definitions of `equals`, `hashCode`, etc., they can be nested. In particular, since you are working with enumeration constants, you may try Java's built-in `EnumSet`:

```
EnumSet.of(Color.CHROM, Color.CHROM)
```

instead of

```
new Color[] {Color.CHROM, Color.CHROM}
```

Whether Hibernate can properly interpret this, however, is a different question.